# taking a value from an object and giving it to another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

hi guys got a real chin scratcher here.

I need to take a value from an array inside of an object

```
$scope.document=[]
$scope.accounts=[{name:"123"},{name:"124"},{name:"125"}]
```

I wanna take the first array and add it to $scope.document I need to do this in a loop.

so in the end I wanna say if  $scope.document has name 123 do something else if $scope.accounts has name 124 do something

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abhac5py/

Comment: Problem explanation could definitely use some clarification of objective

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using basic JavaScript:

```
var documents = [],
    accounts  =[ { name: '123' }, { name: '124' }, { name: '125' } ];

var doc = find(accounts, function(o) { return o.name === '123'; });

if (doc) documents.push(doc);

function find(arr, condition) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (condition(arr[i])) { return arr[i]; break; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nLtjtu53/

You can use whatever logic you want after finding an object in your array, I'm just adding it to documents for this example.

If you want to use some of the built-in [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) functionality, this is one possibility:

```
function find(arr, prop, value) {
    var index = accounts.map(function(o) { return o[prop]; }).indexOf(value);

    return arr[index];
}
```

**Just be mindful that not all browsers are supported.**

You can also use a library like [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) that offers a lot of this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the first emtpy array has to do with it, but you can iterate over the second array and inspect each value as follows:

```
$scope.accounts.forEach(function(obj) {
    switch (obj.value) {
    case 123:
        //Statements executed when obj.value = 123.
        //For instance: add this obj to the other array:
        $scope.document.push(obj);
        break;
    case 124:
        //Statements executed when obj.value = 124 
        break;
    default:
        //Statements executed when none of the values match 
        break;
    }
});
```